# strtotime gives back false result to strings in an array

Tags: php, sql-server, strtotime

If I define an array of strings for strtotime it works fine, but if I query the same array of strings from sql it doesn't show anything, which means the result is false.

This is the code which works fine:

```
$belep=array('5:19:28','9:20:03','12:01:43','15:55:55');
for($i=0;$i<count($belep);$i++){
    $belep[$i]=strtotime($belep[$i]);
    echo $belep[$i].'<br>';
}
$sum=0;
for($j=1;$j<count($belep);$j+=2){
    $sum=$sum+($belep[$j]-$belep[$j-1]);
}
echo "Munkában töltött idő: ".gmdate("H:i:s", $sum);
```

And this is where I got the false result:

```
$belep=array();
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql4 );
if( $stmt3 === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
$c=0;
while($row3=sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $variablename='idopont'.$c;
    $$variablename= $row3['TIMEPART']."<br>";
    echo $variablename.'<br>';
    echo $$variablename.'<br>';
    $belep[$c]=$$variablename;
    $c++;
}

for($i=0;$i<count($belep);$i++){
    $belep[$i]=strtotime($belep[$i]);
    echo $belep[$i].'<br>';
}
$sum=0;
for($j=1;$j<count($belep);$j+=2){
    $sum=$sum+($belep[$j]-$belep[$j-1]);
}
echo "Munkában töltött idő: ".gmdate("H:i:s", $sum);
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt3);
```

If I echo the array in the second example I get the same result of strings as in the first example.
If I check the type of the elements of the array the result is string.
So why strtotime does not work on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code I see

```
while($row3=sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $variablename='idopont'.$c;
  $$variablename= $row3['TIMEPART']."<br>"; // Specially this one
  echo $variablename.'<br>';
  echo $$variablename.'<br>';
  $belep[$c]=$$variablename; // And this one
  $c++;
}
```

If you see the 2 lines I highlighted, you are appending a `<br>` to the date being extracted from the DB (assuming that's the date on the DB). So, supposing you have `2019-08-17` it will now be `2019-08-17<br>` and that's not a valid date.
What I would do (keeping the same code structure), is:

```
while($row3=sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $variablename='idopont'.$c;
  $$variablename= $row3['TIMEPART']; // I removed <br> from here
  echo $variablename.'<br/>';
  echo $$variablename.'<br/><br/>';
  $belep[$c]=$$variablename;
  $c++;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, indeed, that was the problem!!